# Sencha Touch make Dataview dynamic elements draggable

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a dataview that is populated using a store and template so the process is dynamic. I then want to make each of the container Divs (see template) draggable and use the following code. I would have expected just the container divs(image + name) to be draggable but instead the whole DataView is draggable. Was wondering what i am doing wrong?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.allImages', {    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'cams',
requires: [
    'MyApp.store.images'
],
config: {

    title: 'Test',
    store: 'images',
    baseCls: 'camera-list',


    itemTpl: [
        '<div id="camimage">',
            '<div class="image" style="background-image:url({fullimage})"></div>',
            '<div class="name">{address}</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    records: null,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Gainesville'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Path1'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Path2'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Path3'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

},
initialize: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    //get the divs that we want to make draggable
    var images = this.element.select("div[id='camimage']");

    Ext.each(images.elements, function (imageElement) {

        imageElement.draggable = true;
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the life cicle of the component, you must wait until the dataview has rendered, so you can access the elements.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var me = this;
    //get the divs that we want to make draggable
    //
    setTimeout(function (argument) {
        var images = me.element.select("div.image-dataview-item");
        Ext.each(images.elements, function (imageElement) {
            var draggable = new Ext.util.Draggable({
                element: imageElement,
                listeners: {
                    dragstart: function(self, e, startX, startY) {
                        console.log("test dragStart[" + startX + ":" + startY + "]");
                    },
                    drag: function(self, e, newX, newY) {
                        console.log("test drag[" + newX + ":" + newY + "]");
                    },
                    dragend: function(self, e, endX, endY) {
                        console.log("test dragend[" + endX + ":" + endY + "]");
                    }
                }
            });
            draggable.setConstraint({
                min: { x: -Infinity, y: -Infinity },
                max: { x: Infinity, y: Infinity }
            });
            draggable.group = 'base';// Default group for droppable
            draggable.revert = true;
        });
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hardcoded element ID on an item template. You will end up with multiple elements with the same ID. You should change camimage from an id to a class, or if you are really attached to your ID use the record identifier so each div ID is unique.

Comment: Thanks that solved part of the problem but the behavior of the whole containing DataView moving was solved by setting the scrollable config to false. of course this has huge side-effects but another battle as I think the Sencha draggable code is a little weak